# A system became $20\%$ slower than earlier time $T$ should be modeled as $T*1.2$ or $\frac{T}{0.8}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am bit confused in the following question as already states in the topic

> A system became $20\%$ slower than earlier time $T$ it used to take to complete an operation. Should it be modeled as $T*1.2$ or $\frac{T}{0.8}$?

Actually what each of these representation imply? i.e, $T*1.2$ and $\frac{T}{0.8}$? And which would be correct modeling?

Also, What if the system became $20\%$ faster? I have been correctly solving modeling $\frac{T}{1.2}$ but I am curious what $T*0.8$ would mean in this case?

Comment: So let's say that a system has as speed, defined as
$$
S = \frac{1}{T}
$$
If the system becomes $20~\%$ slower, $S$ is reduced by a factor of $0.8$:
$$
0.8 S = \frac{0.8}{T}
$$
I think from this you can already see the answer.

Comment: Thanks @MattiP. What $T*1.2$ imply?

Comment: For that, you can use what you learned from my comment and apply it.

Comment: @MattiP. $16.7\%$ decrease in speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that the task involved is to run (or walk) a distance of one mile.

If you run at speed $S$ miles per hour then the time taken to complete the mile is $T=\frac 1 S$ hours. If you now run $20\%$ slower then your speed is now $S'=0.8S$ and your time to complete the mile is now

$T'=\frac{1}{S'} = \frac{1}{0.8S} = \frac{T}{0.8}$

If instead you have $T'=1.2T$ then we would say you took $20\%$ longer - which is different from running $20\%$ slower.